# not find any control in cell

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
    private void btnSaveStudy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string valueFromlbl = string.Empty;

            for(int i = 0; i < tableContent.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < tableContent.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
                {
                    foreach(Control ctrl in tableContent.Rows[i].Cells[j].Controls)
                    {
                        Label lbl = ctrl as Label;
                        if(lbl != null)
                        {
                            valueFromlbl = lbl.Text;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
HtmlTable table = null;
                HtmlTableRow row = null;
                HtmlTableCell cell = null;
                studyNumber = studyNumber + 1;
                uniqueID = uniqueID + 1;

                for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    table = new HtmlTable();
                    row = new HtmlTableRow();

                    tableContent.Controls.AddAt(i, row);
                    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                    {
                        cell = new HtmlTableCell();
                        cell.Attributes.Add("Class", "csstablelisttd");
                        row.Attributes.Add("Class", "csstextheader");
                        row.Controls.AddAt(j, cell);

                        if(i == 0 && j == 0)
                        {
                            cell.InnerText = "Study : " + Convert.ToInt32(studyNumber);

                        }
                        else if(i == 1 && j == 0)
                        {
                            cell.InnerText = "Modality" + " : " + modality;
                        }
                        else if(i == 2 && j == 0)
                        {
                            cell.InnerText = "Start Date" + " : " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
                        }
                        else if(i == 3 && j == 0)
                        {
                            cell.InnerText = "Accession Number" + " : " + accessionNumber;
                        }
                        else if(i == 4 && j == 0)
                        {
                            Button btnSaveStudy = new Button();
                            btnSaveStudy.ID = "btnSaveStudy" + uniqueID;
                            btnSaveStudy.Text = "Save";
                            btnSaveStudy.Attributes.Add("Class", "cssbutton");
                            cell.Controls.Add(btnSaveStudy);
                            btnSaveStudy.Click += new EventHandler(btnSaveStudy_Click);
                        }
                        if(i == 1 && j == 1)
                        {
                            cell.InnerText = "AE Title" + " : " + schedule_Station_AE_Title;
                        }
                        else if(i == 1 && j == 2)
                        {
                            cell.InnerText = "Station Name" + " : " + schedule_Station_Name;
                        }
                        else if(i == 2 && j == 1)
                        {
                            cell.InnerText = "Start time" + " : " + startTime;
                        }
                        else if(i == 3 && j == 1)
                        {
                            cell.InnerText = "End time" + " : " + endTime;
                        }

                        else if(i == 2 && j == 2)
                        {
                            Label lblPriority = new Label();
                            lblPriority.ID = "lblPriority" + uniqueID;
                            lblPriority.Text = "Priority : ";
                            DropDownList ddlPriority = new DropDownList();
                            ddlPriority.ID = "ddlPriority" + uniqueID;
                            ddlPriority.Attributes.Add("Class", "csstextbox");
                            ddlPriority.Items.Add(new ListItem("MEDIUM", "4"));
                            ddlPriority.Items.Add(new ListItem("STAT", "1"));
                            ddlPriority.Items.Add(new ListItem("HIGH", "2"));
                            ddlPriority.Items.Add(new ListItem("ROUTINE", "3"));
                            ddlPriority.Items.Add(new ListItem("LOW", "5"));
                            cell.Controls.Add(lblPriority);
                            cell.Controls.Add(ddlPriority);
                        }
                        else if(i == 3 && j == 2)
                        {
                            Label lblStudy = new Label();
                            lblStudy.ID = "lblStudy" + uniqueID;
                            lblStudy.Text = "Study : ";
                            DropDownList ddlStudyList = new DropDownList();
                            ddlStudyList = BindStudy(ddlStudyList, Convert.ToInt32(acqModalityID), uniqueID);
                            ddlStudyList.Attributes.Add("Class", "csstextbox");
                            cell.Controls.Add(lblStudy);
                            cell.Controls.Add(ddlStudyList);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }}
I have added controls to table cell but not find any control
```

Comment: Is this ASP.NET? If so, tag it accrodingly. Where did you add the controls and how?

Comment: You're only looking for `Label` controls. Have you run it in debugger to see what controls are there?  You may be looking for `Literal` controls.

Comment: Can you show how you're adding controls? They may not still be there after the postback.

Comment: We really need to know where and how you added theses controls, are you also recreating them on postbacks(in `page_load` at the latest)? Btw, why don't you use a `GridView` instead?

Comment: Also remember that there could be a container control in the cell that has the `Label` inside of it.

Comment: yes there is table inside cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be an issue with the execution order. Remember that your controls are not added until after your click event.  So when your button click fires, the controls need to have been re-added before you can check for their existence.

(I would post this as a comment, but evidently, as I am new, I don't have enough points)

Answer (score 1):

pass in the Page as the root and see if the control you are looking for comes back

```
private Control FindControlRecursive(Control rootControl, string controlID)
{
    if (rootControl.ID == controlID) return rootControl;

    foreach (Control controlToSearch in rootControl.Controls)
    {
        Control controlToReturn = 
            FindControlRecursive(controlToSearch, controlID);
        if (controlToReturn != null) return controlToReturn;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have simply forgotten to add the table itself to the page's control-collection.

```
Page.Controls.Add(table);
```

(it would be better to add it to a container control like `PlaceHolder` or `Panel` instead)